# Reload Vim highlight setting and colorscheme

Tags: vim

If I change Vim's `highlight` setting, how do I "reload" it for colorschemes to take effect?

So, in my case, I remove `highlight`'s cursor line number

```
se hl-=N:CursorLineNr
```

Changing `highlight` from

> highlight=8:SpecialKey,@:NonText,d:Directory,e:ErrorMsg,i:IncSearch,l:Search,m:Mor
>       eMsg,M:ModeMsg,n:LineNr,**N:CursorLineNr**,r:Question,s:StatusLine,S:StatusLineNC,c:Vert
>       Split,t:Title,v:Visual,V:VisualNOS,w:WarningMsg,W:WildMenu,f:Folded,F:FoldColumn,A:D
>       iffAdd,C:DiffChange,D:DiffDelete,T:DiffText,>:SignColumn,-:Conceal,B:SpellBad,P:Spel
>       lCap,R:SpellRare,L:SpellLocal,+:Pmenu,=:PmenuSel,x:PmenuSbar,X:PmenuThumb,*:TabLine,
>       #:TabLineSel,_:TabLineFill,!:CursorColumn,.:CursorLine,o:ColorColumn

to

> highlight=8:SpecialKey,@:NonText,d:Directory,e:ErrorMsg,i:IncSearch,l:Search,m:Mor
>       eMsg,M:ModeMsg,n:LineNr,r:Question,s:StatusLine,S:StatusLineNC,c:VertSplit,t:Title,v
>       :Visual,V:VisualNOS,w:WarningMsg,W:WildMenu,f:Folded,F:FoldColumn,A:DiffAdd,C:DiffCh
>       ange,D:DiffDelete,T:DiffText,>:SignColumn,-:Conceal,B:SpellBad,P:SpellCap,R:SpellRar
>       e,L:SpellLocal,+:Pmenu,=:PmenuSel,x:PmenuSbar,X:PmenuThumb,*:TabLine,#:TabLineSel,_:
>       TabLineFill,!:CursorColumn,.:CursorLine,o:ColorColumn

*(I've emphasized the change.)*

But the cursor line number is still "highlighted"!

Changing `highlight` doesn't update the colorscheme—so how do I "force" an update? I've tried setting syntax coloring off then on again and changing colorschemes to no avail.

Comment: Why would you want to modify this mapping to highlight groups during runtime?

Comment: If you remove something from this option, Vim will just use defaults. It won’t stop highlighting this thing. But if you change option to use *another* highlighting group, changes will be seen immediately.

Comment: This step is very useful when debugging Vim syntax highlighting files under `$HOME/.vim/syntax` subdirectory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reset/clear a highlight-group, you could use `:hi` cmd.

in your case, try with:

```
:hi CursorLineNr NONE   #this will disable the hl setting for the given group

:hi clear CursorLineNr  #this will set the given group's highlight setting to default.
```

`:h hi` to see detail

if you want to reload your colorscheme, you could `:color xxx`

hope it helps